# Rest Api Name when the functionality is similar

Tags: rest, post, naming-conventions

If the requirement is to have two end point (they cannot be same endpoint due to logic in code) and they both return book id after saving book. What should the api endpoint name be?

I cannot not use /book/save for both of them. I am not sure if using version control is good idea because that indicates it is newer version of api.

Answer (score 0):

Actions/endpoints are the wrong lens to use; what's important in REST is your *resource model*.

It's perfectly normal to have one resource that can be modified in different ways.

```
POST /collection-of-books
```

This request lines tells general purpose components that we are making a change to `/collection-of-books`.  The implementation of that change might depend on the specific payload contained in the message-body of the request, and that's *fine*.

Think about how this might look on the web: you would have two different forms in an html document; the user chooses the form that fits their needs, edits the input controls with some information, then submits the form.  Your code receiving the HTTP request would look at which form data was in the body of the request, and choose the correct implementation to use.

---

> What should the api endpoint name be?

Anything you like that's consistent with your local spelling conventions.

Resource identifiers are similar to variable names / function names.  The machines *don't care*.  The machines only care about whether identifiers are the same (meaning we are talking about the same resource) or different (meaning we are not talking about the same resource).  From the perspective of REST, any spelling consistent with the production rules defined by RFC 3986 is fine.

So your spelling choices depend on other local concerns (what do you want to see in the documentation? what do you want to see when you are reading the access logs? what do you want clients to see in their browser histories?).  Broadly, what spelling makes things easiest for the humans you care the most about.

My suggestion would be to identify the resources in your resource model; when you know why two resources are different, you'll have a clearer idea about the spelling of the resource identifiers.